# Creating a close sourced Python program

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to write a python code that is un-decryptable. Is this possible there are things like `pyarmor` and such that would enable a secure source code but I am looking for something that is not decryptable to maximize the security. The aim is to create a secure close-sourced program in python.

Comment: In short.....no....

Comment: This isn't possible for any language afaik. All you can do is to make it more difficult for anyone who wants to try. You're potentially up against skilled individuals with expensive RE software, so it's an "arms race" against them. Unless there are hardware protections being made use of, but that again just makes it harder.

Comment: do I have to change programming languages to have a close source program

Comment: Even if you chose a language like C where source isn't distributed, someone can just load your program into Ghidra or IDA and decompile your code. If you make use of packing on top of that, someone can load it into a debugger like OllyDBG and wait until your program decrypts itself.

Comment: Might be a good time to think “cloud” and offload some computations to a server *you* control.  Of course, whether or not that makes sense in your problem and data domain is another issue.  This is in addtion to @Carcigenicate very valid point.

Comment: A closed source program is in no way "more secure" than an open source one. They are different, but neither is inherently more secure. You should not rely on security by obscurity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is an interpreted language, which means that the interpreter needs the source code *at runtime* in order to work. This means that even if you were able to encrypt the source code, the interpreter would still need to decrypt the source code to work at all so there is no *100%* safe option. There are a few tactics you may want to look into though:

1. Obfuscation, which works by making the source code less readable
2. Compilation, which converts the source to machine code (Cython does this I think), which makes it harder to reverse-engineer

Could you make a decryption interpreter for Python? Probably. Would the performance be terrible? Also likely. Is it much easier to do one of the two above? Definitely. Or just switch to a different language which supports compilation and instruction-level obfuscation (like C/C++, Java, or C#).

Comment: what is a instruction-level obfuscation if I may ask

Comment: Actual machine instruction obfuscation is almost never used since it's difficult enough to reverse-engineer on its own. However, many obfuscators will mangle/hash method and object names so that their intended purpose is unclear. Additionally, the obfuscation tool may also introduce dead/misleading code and erroneous control statements that don't really do anything.